# Getting a List of all files and subdirectories in a given directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, html5-filesystem

I would like to be able to list the files of a directory in JavaScript in this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#file-input").on("change", function(e) {
        var thefiles = e.target.files
        console.log(e.target.files.name)
        $.each(thefiles, function(i, item) {
            console.log(item)
            var thefile = item
            $("#thelist").append("FILES: " + thefile.name + "<br />")
        })
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file-input" webkitdirectory='test/' directory='/Users/genysix/Desktop/test'>
<div id="thelist"></div>
```

But I would like to be able to use it without having to have an Input File but by separating the hard path of the directory it must list.
Example: 'C:/temp/'

If you can help me I would be grateful

Comment: I am not sure what you're looking for. The file picker dialog in Chrome only showed folders, not files. This may be browser or system-specific. Can you provide more details?

Comment: No, I want to open a folder, then get all the file in this folder